# How to conditionally add a #include file based on viewport

Tags: php

I need to add an include file based on the viewport of the device or PC.

```
<!--#include virtual="/main/header.inc"-->
```

I have media queries setup. Like this

```
@media all and (min-width: 600px) { 
.visible-phone{
display:none;
}
}
```

I have tried placing the include in a div like this

```
<div class="visible-phone">
    <!--#include virtual="/main/phone-header.inc"-->
</div>
```

But it doesn't appear to work.
How can I include an include based on viewport?

thanks in advance

Comment: To include files in php, you can use <?php include 'path/to/file.ext'; ?>

Answer (score 1):

If you need to include the file in question into your code, you can use the following

```
<div class="visible-phone">
    <?php include '/main/phone-header.inc'; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working.. do I need to include 'virtual'? Doesn't work if I remove the <div> tag either. Any ideas? thx

Comment: I have no idea what 'virtual' is. What's the entire path to your file you're wanting to include?

Comment: This is the original line.  I don't know match about PHP... thx again    Path would be  /main

Comment: <!--#include virtual="/main/header.inc"-->

Comment: virtual= has no meaning in the world of PHP, so I'm not understanding if that's part of your file's path. In your original question, could you edit it and post a screen shot of your directory? Also, are you running this on a server somewhere? You need to ensure the environment you're on can execute PHP.

Comment: it works if I do  <?php virtual('/main/phone-header.inc';?>